# How do you Return a list of verses that belong to that book

Tags: python, string, list, int, append

I am trying to tead the text data for the King James Version of the bible from the filesystem and translate that data into Python data structures Access books, chapters and verses from the previously produced data structures Search the KJV bible for text.

```
parse_line(line):
```

Given a line of text (i.e. a string) from the `bible.tsv` file, strip all trailing whitespace (using the ".strip" method), then split it using a tab character separator ("\t")

Convert the 2nd and 3rd elements (chapter and verse) of the resulting list into integers

Return that list

This is what I have as my code for `parse_line`. I believe this code is correct.

```
def parse_line(line):
    line = aline.strip().split('\t')
    line[1] = int(line[1])
    line[2] = int(line[2])
    return line
```

parse_kjv_tsv():

Create an empty list to store the verses in the bible.tsv file

Open the kjv.tsv file for reading

For each line of the file, pass that line to parse_line and append the output of parse_line to a list of verses

Return the created list of verses

This is what I have as my code for `parse_kjv_tsv()`:

```
def parse_kjv_tsv():
    kjv_file = open('kjv.tsv', 'r')
    verses = []
    for line in kjv_file:
        verse = parse_line(line)
        verses.append(verse)
    kjv_file.close()
    return verses
```

It's not returning the right information. I need For each line of the file, pass that line to `parse_line` and append the output of `parse_line` to a list of verses. then, Return the created list of verses.

For example the output should be:

```
>>> import bible
>>> verses = bible.parse_kjv_tsv()
>>> verses[0]
['ge', 0, 0, 'In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.']
```

Notice that the 2nd and 3rd elements of "verses[0]" are integers, not strings.

Access the KJV

In this portion, you will be creating functions to access books, chapters and verses from the previously-created Python data structure. You will need to create the following functions:

I need help with get_book(verses, book)

```
get_book(verses, book):
```

Given:

- a list of verses (i.e. the output of `parse_kjv_tsv`) and
- a book name (a string)

Return a list of verses that belong to that book

```
get_chapter(verses, book, chapter):
```

Given:

- a list of verses (i.e. the output of `parse_kjv_tsv`) and
- a book name (a string) and
- a chapter number (an integer)

Return a list of verses that belong to that book and that chapter

```
get_verse(verses, book, chapter, verse):
```

Given:

- a list of verses (i.e. the output of `parse_kjv_tsv`) and
- a book name (a string) and
- a chapter number (an integer)
- a verse number (an integer)

Return a string of the text of that verse

```
search_bible(verses, search_text):
```

Given:

- a list of verses (i.e. the output of `parse_kjv_tsv`) and
- a string to search for in those verses

Return a dictionary of your search results

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting of your question. Please [read up on this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure to use appropriate markup. Not every bit of descriptive text should be bold (surrounded by `**`) or a heading (beginning with one or more `#`), and code blocks (indented by four spaces) should only be used for code or file content. You are also asking many questions at once, and this is likely too broad. Read [ask] for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do

```
parse_kjv_tsv():
    # Create an empty list to store the verses in the bible.tsv file
    verses = []
    # Open the kjv.tsv file for reading
    with open('kjv.tsv', 'r') as f:
        # For each line of the file, pass that line to parse_line and append   
        # the output of parse_line to a list of verses
        for line in f:
            verses.append(parse_line(line))
    # Return the created list of verses
    return verses
```

---

FYI—the snippet above assumes that your `parse_line` implementation is correct.  You should test that before using this.  I think you may be missing a `return`.

Comment: you can just do this (in the with statement): `return [parse_line(line) for line in f]`

Answer (score 0):

your parse line is incorrect.

```
parts = line.strip().split('\t')
parts[1] = int(parts[1])
parts[2] = int(parts[2])
return parts
```

if you do that, your code for work up till the end of parse kjv! you were basically redefining the parameters of the function which made it unfruitful.